# JavaDoc for overloaded methods that just call the same method but with null values?

Tags: java, overloading, javadoc

So I'm writing `JavaDoc` for overloaded methods and I can't get my head around the best way to format them. My project is a Doctor Appointment Viewing system that has the following functionality:

- Doctor objects have an LinkedList of Appointment objects
- Appointment objects can be created containing patient name and date
- User can log in as a Doctor
- User can list the Appointments
- User can create a new Appointment

So an example in my system is for a method inside the Doctor object called 'isAvailable(Date date)'. The method takes a date parameter and then checks all of the Appointment objects in the Doctor object to see if the Doctor is available for that date. If so, a new Appointment object is created and added to the LinkedList for that doctor.

Now, I have an overloaded `isAvailable(String date)` method that does the following:

- Takes the date as a String type
- Parses a Date object from the String date
- Calls isAvaialble(Date) with the parsed Date object

Am I supposed to write JavaDoc for both of them and pretend that the isAvailable(String Date) carries out the functionality of checking if the Doctor is available or am I supposed to say that it just converts the String to a Date and then calls isAvailable(Date)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

how about

```
 /**
  * Parses the argument into a Date object, then calls {@link Doctor#isAvailable(Date)}
  */
```